# How to debug android app when using my real map api?

Tags: android, google-maps

I developed android app. I generated my own keystore and got api for release app. Everything is fine. But when I try to debug my app with this map api key, while I developing it, I can't see my maps. If I export apk and deploy it to device, everthing works fine again.

What should I do, while I developing my app and debugging it to see maps.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between your debug key and your production key. If your debug.keystore does not have an API key associated with it, you won't see map tiles (or vector images).

In OSX for example... the debug.keystore is in ~/.android/

Check to ensure that you have your debug.keystore setup with an API key as well.

Comment: In addition, you will need to switch between these keys. Eventually, the new build system under development will make this very easy. For now, either make the changes in your layout file, or create your `MapView` in Java code, where you can use `Build.DEBUG` to selectively supply either the debug or production Maps V1 API key.

Comment: You need to implement what CommonsWare is talking about as early on as possible (it will make future development *much* easier). However, I wouldn't recommend the continued use of the Maps API v1 any longer. Google is about to stop issuing new keys... and v2 is far superior (though it isn't without issue). I would recommend incorporating that.

Comment: @CommonsWare So I need to change api key, when I am on development or release. Cant I use my production key on debug mode?

Comment: @gurcan15: I do not know what you mean by "on debug mode", sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare I mean, I cant use my production key both on product and while I debugging. I need to change api while I debugging it.

Comment: @gurcan15: You are welcome to do a manual build in debug mode and sign it with the production key, and see if that works. I have no idea how best to do that from within Eclipse. A production build in Eclipse will run your app through ProGuard, and I doubt that the result will work in the Eclipse debugger. "I need to change api while I debugging it" -- I do not know what you mean by this, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry for my english.For exmp,I begin to develop app that use google map.To see map,I should use map api key with using debug.keystore. For example my map api key is "12345" I write it to MapView and I can use map well. Than, I will put my app to market, I have to use my own keystore and generate new map api key with my own keystore. I change my MapView api to new api on layout that is "678900".

Comment: @gurcan15: "Than I need to improve my app and I open it on Eclipse, I do some changes and try to run on emulator. Now because of using real map api key" -- you replace your production API key with "12345" when you are doing development.

Comment: Continue...
 Ok everthing is fine. Than I need to improve my app and I open it on  Eclipse, I do some changes and try to run on emulator. Now because of using real map api key ("67890")I cant see maps, I need to switch old map api key ("12345") that generated by debug.keystore